Error while switching to secondary RDS region using hikari
I have existing code where Datasource is created using hikari.
I am working on adding new functionality where if current rds is down application should switch to secondary rds.
In docker compose file I added new image for local testing
For this I updated docker-compose.yml file as following
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql-east:
    image: docker.ouroath.com:4443/docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.35
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'  # Exposing MySQL for east region on port 3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-east-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql-west:
    image: docker.ouroath.com:4443/docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.35
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'  # Exposing MySQL for west region on port 3307
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-west-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  mockServer:
    image: docker.ouroath.com:4443/docker.io/mockserver/mockserver:mockserver-5.13.1
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
    environment:
      MOCKSERVER_PROPERTY_FILE: /config/mockserver.properties
      MOCKSERVER_INITIALIZATION_JSON_PATH: /config/initializerJson.json
    volumes:
      - './config:/config'
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    image: docker.ouroath.com:4443/cloud/redis-docker:20211022-215552
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

After that I updated application.yml file whith secondary db properties
db:
  east:
    host: "mysql-east"  # Using the Docker service name
    port: 3306
    database: senderhub
    username: root
    password: ""  # Empty password as per Docker Compose configuration
    region: us-east-1

  west:
    host: "mysql-west"  # Using the Docker service name
    port: 3307
    database: senderhub
    username: root
    password: ""  # Empty password as per Docker Compose configuration
    region: us-west-2


I updated DataSourceConfiguration.java to support switch to secondary rds
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${db.east.host}")
    private String hostEast;

    @Value("${db.east.port}")
    private String portEast;

    @Value("${db.east.database}")
    private String databaseEast;

    @Value("${db.east.username}")
    private String usernameEast;

    @Value("${db.east.password}")
    private String passwordEast;

    @Value("${db.east.region}")
    private String regionEast;

    @Value("${db.west.host}")
    private String hostWest;

    @Value("${db.west.port}")
    private String portWest;

    @Value("${db.west.database}")
    private String databaseWest;

    @Value("${db.west.username}")
    private String usernameWest;

    @Value("${db.west.password}")
    private String passwordWest;

    @Value("${db.west.region}")
    private String regionWest;

    private HikariDataSource eastDataSource;
    private HikariDataSource westDataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        logger.info("Initializing DataSourceConfiguration for east and west databases.");
    }

    // Create a DataSource for us-east-1
    @Bean
    public DataSource eastDataSource() {
        logger.info("Configuring east DB: host={}, port={}, database={}, username={}, region={}",
                hostEast, portEast, databaseEast, usernameEast, regionEast);

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + hostEast + ":" + portEast + "/" + databaseEast);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(usernameEast);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(passwordEast);  // This will handle the empty password scenario
        applyHikariSettings(hikariConfig);
        eastDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        logger.info("East DB configured successfully.");
        return eastDataSource;
    }

    // Create a DataSource for us-west-2
    @Bean
    public DataSource westDataSource() {
        logger.info("Configuring west DB: host={}, port={}, database={}, username={}, region={}",
                hostWest, portWest, databaseWest, usernameWest, regionWest);

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + hostWest + ":" + portWest + "/" + databaseWest);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(usernameWest);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(passwordWest);  // This will handle the empty password scenario
        applyHikariSettings(hikariConfig);
        westDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        logger.info("West DB configured successfully.");
        return westDataSource;
    }

    // Apply common Hikari settings for both DataSources
    private void applyHikariSettings(HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);  // 60 seconds
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(5000);   // 5 seconds
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);      // 30 minutes
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(600000);       // 10 minutes
        hikariConfig.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);  // Don't fail on initialization

        logger.debug("HikariCP settings applied: connectionTimeout=60000, validationTimeout=5000, maxLifetime=1800000, idleTimeout=600000");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource routingDataSource() {
        logger.info("Setting up DynamicRoutingDataSource.");

        DynamicRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new DynamicRoutingDataSource();

        // Configure routing data sources
        HashMap<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put("east", eastDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put("west", westDataSource());

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(eastDataSource());  // Start with east DB

        // Schedule a health check every 30 seconds
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                logger.debug("Checking health of the east DB...");
                if (eastDataSource().getConnection().isValid(5)) {
                    if (!routingDataSource.isEastDbUp()) {
                        routingDataSource.switchToEastDb();
                        logger.info("East DB is back up. Switched to east region.");
                    } else {
                        logger.debug("East DB is healthy and already in use.");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (routingDataSource.isEastDbUp()) {
                    logger.warn("East DB is down. Switching to west region.");
                    routingDataSource.switchToWestDb();
                } else {
                    logger.debug("East DB is still down, staying on west DB.");
                }
            }
        }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return routingDataSource;
    }
}

Here I am using AbstractRoutingDataSource for Dynamic Data Source Routing . DynamicRoutingDataSource.java is used for dynaic routing
public class DynamicRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicRoutingDataSource.class);

    private boolean isEastDbUp = true;  // Start with east DB assumed up

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        logger.debug("Determining current DB region: {}", isEastDbUp ? "east" : "west");
        return isEastDbUp ? "east" : "west";
    }

    public void switchToEastDb() {
        logger.info("Switching to the east DB...");
        isEastDbUp = true;
    }

    public void switchToWestDb() {
        logger.warn("Switching to the west DB...");
        isEastDbUp = false;
    }

    public boolean isEastDbUp() {
        return isEastDbUp;
    }
}

Please note that I have not added import statements to save time.
Eariler when I used to hit any api it was working since new changes API is not getting any response.
I am using rancher desktop on local. all images are running fine on rancher
Can someone please help ?

I am skeptical of your approach because applications connect to a single cluster endpoint in multi-az RDS instance. AWS takes care of the fail-over to the secondary. Secondary is a read-only instance and sometimes applications connect to it only for read operations to increase performance.
If you still want to use separate endpoints for write and read operations respectively, I have a few suggestions for your code:
In the health check section, you should open the connection using try-with-resource:
try (Connection connection = eastDataSource().getConnection()) {
   if(connection.isValid(5)) {
      //rest of the logic
   }

}

Because you are not closing the connections, they are getting exhausted.

@pravin kottawar, let me know, if my answer helped, else I have another option where you can completely avoid the health check.

thank you . I will try this and let you know . How AWS takes care of the fail-over to the secondary ?

That is all internally handled by AWS, you dont have to worry about it.All you have to do is provision a multi az RDS instance, get the cluster endpoint and use it to instantiate your datasource bean. Cluster endpoint takes care of routing to the active instance.

AWS offers Amazon Aurora Global databases with full MySQL support, this option handles the cross-region fail-over for you by offering a single global endpoint that your application connects to.
Take a look at their documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html
Implementing the fail-over switch in your application is a bit more complicated than your current code, if you want to fix it for education purposes take these things into consideration:

HikariCP is a connection pooling library, means it creates multiple connections and hold them into a pool.
When you're calling eastDataSource().getConnection().isValid(5) these connections are not being closed automatically, instead:

  try(val connection = (eastDataSource().getConnection()) {
  if (connection.isValid(5)

Failing to do so will cause connection leakage, pool depletion and even resource exhaustion causing your application's performance to degrade or even fail to operate.

You're dealing with a multi-threading application, your current mechanism for handling which db is up is not thread safe: private boolean isEastDbUp, try instead using AtomicBoolean.

Each application has a limited number of threads it can support, and they compete for resources as well, handling an incoming API call is typically a high priority resource whereas scheduled tasks are treated as standard or low priority. Under high loads, it could be that Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate() won't be executed every 30 seconds, or worst it may hang in the execution queue forever.

If you're considering using multiple regions in your application, likely your application will also have auto-scaling to handle traffic (more than one instance of the same application running at once), with your current implementation of storing the state (isEastDbUp) in memory, each instance will have to wait for a request before it switches database.



mysql-west:
ports:
- '3307:3306'
is it copy paste mistake?
also, use try-with-resource for db connection, statement and resultset.
